# Floating action button in android not displaying correctly

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am trying to change the default `FloatingActionButton` icon to a `add circle` icon. I have downloaded the `icon ic_add_circle_white_18dp` from [material.io](https://material.io/icons/#ic_add_circle) and added it to the `drawable directory` inside the andorid project. However when I try to use it inside my activity it displays as a black inner icon as in image

[image]

However I want the `FAB` icon to look like

[image]

My FAB icon xml looks like

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_fab"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

I have tried setting the `app:backgroundTint` value but it doesn't effect the inner icon style

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing Clipart corresponding to the add icon from image asset works:

**Steps:**

```
1. Right Click on res.
2. Select New->Image Asset
3. In Icon type, select Action Bar and Tab Icons
4. Provide a name
5. Select ClipArt in Asset type and the click on the Clip Art icon.
6. From the content section select add button
7. In theme set HOLO_DARK
6. Click Next and then finish
```

[image]

[image]
In order to use this as an icon, include the following in your XML. Note that to use the icon as source `android:src="@drawable/ic_add_fab"` is used

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_fab" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading and using icon with name "add" instead of "add circle"

Comment: Anyways thank you, your answer helped me reach the solution. See my answer for the full solution. Upvote for help :)

Comment: Thank you :) @ShubhamKhatri

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                   android:id="@+id/logout_btn"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@mipmap/logout"
                   app:rippleColor="@null"
                   app:backgroundTint="@null"
                   app:fabSize="normal"
                   android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                   android:scaleType="center"/>
```

Also src icon should be the same according to the requirement.

I used `140x140 for xhdpi drawable`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `app:srcCompat=` use `app:src=` for images.

Or use `fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add);` to programatically set the image.

Comment: Anyways thank you, your answer set me up in the right direction. See my answer for the full solution. +1 for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set scaleType for it to be rendered properly:

```
 android:scaleType="center"
```